# Is it possible to input a list as an attribute to a method within a class?

Tags: python, class, methods

I am struggling on this Codecademy project.  I am trying to input a list when calling a class object, to make my code more concise and practical, rather than having to explicitly define the list as a variable to be attributed to the method. I want the function "Menu.calculate_bill" to work in this way. Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
class Menu:
  def __init__(self, name, items, start_time, end_time):
    self.name = name
    self.items = items
    self.start_time = start_time
    self.end_time = end_time
  
  def __repr__(self):
    return self.name + ' menu available from ' + str(self.start_time) + ' o\'clock' + " to " + str(self.end_time) + ' o\'clock'
  

  def calculate_bill(self, purchased_items = []):
    total_price = 0
    for item in purchased_items:
      total_price += self.name[item][0]
    return(total_price)

brunch = Menu('brunch', {'pancakes': 7.50, 'waffles': 9.00, 'burger': 11.00, 'home fries': 4.50, 'coffee': 1.50, 'espresso': 3.00, 'tea': 1.00, 'mimosa': 10.50, 'orange juice': 3.50}, 11, 16)

early_bird = Menu('early-bird', {'salumeria plate': 8.00, 'salad and breadsticks (serves 2, no refills)': 14.00, 'pizza with quattro formaggi': 9.00, 'duck ragu': 17.50, 'mushroom ravioli (vegan)': 13.50, 'coffee': 1.50, 'espresso': 3.00}, 15, 18)

dinner = Menu('dinner', {'crostini with eggplant caponata': 13.00, 'caesar salad': 16.00, 'pizza with quattro formaggi': 11.00, 'duck ragu': 19.50, 'mushroom ravioli (vegan)': 13.50, 'coffee': 2.00, 'espresso': 3.00}, 17, 23)

kids = Menu('kids', {'chicken nuggets': 6.50, 'fusilli with wild mushrooms': 12.00, 'apple juice': 3.00}, 11, 21)

Menu.calculate_bill(['pancakes', 'home fries', 'coffee'])
```

Comment: Yes to the title question.  If you are having a problem, then explain it.  This code runs without producing an error or output.

Comment: You need to call `calculate_bill()` on an instance, e.g. `brunch.calculate_bill([...])`

Comment: `self.name[item][0]` makes no sense. `self.name` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Beware the mutable default argument (even though you don't modify it here, so it doesn't rear its ugly head)

Comment: The ugly in this case is when `calculate_bill` is called on the class, `self` is the purchase list.  Better to not have a default at all and catch the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prices are in `self.items`, not `self.names`. You don't need to use `[0]`.

```
  def calculate_bill(self, purchased_items = []):
    total_price = 0
    for item in purchased_items:
      total_price += self.items[item]
    return(total_price)
```

Since `calculate_bill()` is an instance method, you have to call it on an instance.

```
print(brunch.calculate_bill(['pancakes', 'home fries', 'coffee']))
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I forgot that you could call the method onto an instance and also forgot that I had created the items attribute when writing that portion.